# Allow authors to use their own PayPal account and payment process automation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

I am working on a classifieds site where people post their product to sell.

At the moment, all the purchases being credited into site administrator PayPal account, and site administrator then manually transfers 95% of the money back to author's account.
Is it possible to automate this process? And allow site user "authors" to use their personal Paypal account?

I want the automated payment process in the way that for every purchase from site 5 percent of total pay go to site administrator and the rest to authors PayPal account.

Comment: even on a good day this site is not a support channel for paypal, and neither for WC

Comment: @MarkKaplun, My question is related to Wordpress and Wordpress commerce! and implementation of a payment system to a Wordpress site. And therefore I addressed the concern in WordPress StackExchange.

Comment: please read the description of the woocommerce tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal offer two ways of doing this:

**Parallel Payments**

This allows you to essentially conduct 2 transactions (each with their own line item) in one go.

The end-user adds their information to your cart, and get's forwarded to the PayPal Gateway. They see 2 distinct line items:

- Your vendors product info @ 95% of the total
- Your fee @ 5% of the total

This is super-easy to set up. All you'd need to do is store the vendors PayPal information in an additional `user_meta` field, and drag it out before sending the end-user to PayPal.

The two line items, however, can be a bit daunting for less-savvy end-users; and may result in a reduced completion rate.

**Chained Payments**

This allows you to take a single payment from the end-user. PayPal then processes the payment, and automatically forwards the specified percentage (or fixed dollar amount) to your vendor.

This is better for the end-user experience, but is a challenge to set up.

**Check out** PayPal's [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) for info on how to implement.

---

**Edit:** Sorry - I missed the WooCommerce tag on your post...

IgniteWoo have already created a plugin that might do the job: [WooCommerce Vendor Stores](http://ignitewoo.com/woocommerce-extensions-plugins-themes/woocommerce-vendor-stores/)